# Minecraft execute tellraw's clickEvent from original entity, not player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm using a command like this:

```
/execute @e[type=ArmorStand] ~ ~ ~ tellraw @a[score_goto=-1]
  {
    "selector": "@e[type=ArmorStand,r=1]",
    "clickEvent": {
      "action": "run_command",
      "value": "/tp @p ~ ~ ~"
    },
    "color":"blue"
  }
```

To try and make each armor stand in the world say their name (in blue), and, if the player clicks the armor stand's name in-chat they will be teleported to that armor stand.

Currently, it looks like this:

[image: Chat shows two blue armour stand names, Command_Hub and Command_Tester]

And, when I click either of the two names, I'd like to be teleported to that armor stand, hence the

```
"clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/tp @p ~ ~ ~"}
```

part within the command.

However, because `run_command` apparently only inserts the command into the player's chat, I just get teleported to wherever I currently am when I click any name.

So, I tried:

```
"clickEvent": {
  "action": "run_command",
  "value": [
    "/tp @p @e[type=ArmorStand,name=",
    {"selector": "@e[type=ArmorStand,r=1"},
    "]"
  ]
}
```

Thinking that maybe the JSON in value would be parsed, producing my desired value of

```
"value": "/tp @p @e[type=ArmorStand,name=Name_Of_This_Armor_Stand]"
```

but no luck.

Everything I've tried just doesn't seem to work, can someone please help me find a way to make a tellraw clickEvent teleport the player to the entity which executed the tellraw command?

---

## TL;DR

Please help me find a way to make a tellraw clickEvent teleport the player to the entity which executed the tellraw command?

Comment: As an aside, you are aware that only ops will be able to do this, right?  The `run_command` uses whatever privileges the user has, and only ops can `tp`.

Comment: @MBraedley Yes, it's my single-player world though. I don't plan on inviting many people at all. Thanks though :)

Comment: Can't think of a simple way to do this; I think you'd probably have to give each ArmorStand something unique (e.g: a name) then run a separate command for each ArmorStand. As a side note, because of the inconsistent way Mojang implemented relative coordinates, something like `/tp @p ~ ~2 ~` will always teleport `@p` 2 blocks up from `@p`, rather than 2 blocks up from the executer of the command like how relative coordinates in other commands would work.

Comment: @colorfusion `Can't think of a simple way to do this` - nether can I, that's why I'm asking here; I think, by this point, "simple" is completely out of the question. Also, my armor stands already have names, and an execute command is already running `tellraw` for each armor stand. I disagree that Mojang's implementation of the `tp` command is inconsistent; it works exactly as one'd expect. It's just in this case, I need a way for the tellraw-er to run a command, as opposed to the player.

Comment: This is tough.  You need to inject a variable into the `clickEvent:{value:}`, but there isn't a way to do that.

Comment: @MBraedley That's what I realised, so I'm now wondering whether or not there's a work-around.

Comment: @theonlygusti *"I disagree that Mojang's implementation of the tp command is inconsistent; it works exactly as one'd expect."* - may work as you'd expect, but it's still inconsistent implementation. If the coordinates were relative to the executer as they are with other commands, then you could do both what you can currently and a lot more. Anyway, are you fine with running a different command for each ArmorStand? If so, I could post an answer that does that.

Comment: @colorfusion But they are relative to the executer; the tellraw clickEvent simulates the player (clicker) executing the command. The reason it's difficult to simply make a separate, customised command for each armorstand is because there could be any number of armorstands. Unless your answer can handle variable numbers of armorstands, then it will be no more than what I have currently implemented.

Comment: @theonlygusti `/tp` relative coordinates are relative to the target, not the executer. In how you currently have it set up, the executer and the target (`@p`) are the same person. You can test this by putting something like `/tp @p ~ ~2 ~` in a command block, and note how you are teleported to a location 2 blocks above yourself (`@p`, the target), rather than 2 blocks above the command block (the executer). Compare this with another command (e.g: `/playsound entity.player.splash neutral @p ~ ~2 ~`) where the sound is played relative to the executer, rather than the target.

Comment: @colorfusion But in my case, the executer is the target.

Comment: @theonlygusti Which is part of what your problem is. I mentioned this as a side note because, even if you were to execute tellraws clickevent from original entity rather than the player, `/tp @p ~ ~ ~` would still not work. `/tp @p ~ ~ ~` never does anything.

Comment: @colorfusion When I first wrote that, I was hoping `~ ~ ~` might reference the armorstand's coordinates. I see what you mean now though.

Comment: @theonlygusti: And this is why relative coords for `tp` is inconsistent with everything else. The current functionality could be achieved with `/execute @p ~ ~ ~ tp @p ~10 ~10 ~10`.

Answer (score 2):

Do this for all of your armor stands. I believe this is the only way for it to work. It is going to be more command blocks, but I think its the only working one.

```
/execute @e[type=ArmorStand,name=(insertname)] ~ ~ ~ tellraw @a[score_goto=-1]
  {
    "selector": "@e[type=ArmorStand,r=1]",
    "clickEvent": {
      "action": "run_command",
      "value": "/tp @p @e[type=ArmorStand,name=(insertname)]"
    },
    "color":"blue"
  }
```

Comment: I also think it might be the only working method, but I was trying to avoid having to do this. I'd like to be able to automate the creation of these 'waypoints', and creating a new command block for each one is a tedious business.

Comment: I am sorry @theonlygusti but it is the only way I know of. but i figured i try and help

Comment: If you can think of a way to summon command blocks with a certain command and the name of the armor stand then this answer could become useful.

Comment: I am sorry to say I dont think it would work without manually implanting the name in the command block. I could be wrong but i do not know how it would work.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this on non-op players using scoreboards and the `trigger` command.

**First**, setup an objective with the `trigger`criteria:

```
scoreboard objectives add OBJName trigger
```

Now enable players to use the trigger command (more below):

```
scoreboard players enable PLAYER OBJName
```

Now that it is enabled, instead of doing the `tp` command directly use this command:

```
/trigger OBJName set 1
```

This will set the non-op's score of OBJName to 1. Now you can use an execute command to teleport the player:

```
execute @a[score_OBJNaNe_min=1] ~ ~ ~ tp @p @e[type=Armorstand,name=x]
```

This tests for players with a score of 1 in `OBJName`, then teleports them to the @e entity. To TP to an Armorstand, it needs the `customname` nbt tag set and that value to replace X in the above command

Next, you most likely want to setup protection. When you use the tellraw, you should enable the player then disable when you don't want them to be able to use it.

When you say the `tellraw`, also execute this:

```
scoreboard players enable PLAYER OBJName
```

Then, when they click the `tellraw` do your stuff then use this

```
scoreboard players disable PLAYER OBJName
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this isn't actually what I asked for. I want to know how I can teleport the player to the armor stand which executed `tellraw`. All of what you just told me, I already knew anyway.

Comment: @theonlygusti I'm on mobile so I accidentally pressed submit. Updated with Armorstand stuff

Comment: No, really, this post does not answer my question at all. I learned nothing from your attempt at answer, how can I teleport the player to one of several armorstands (variable number) using this method? I'd downvote, but don't yet have the rep on this site.

Comment: The reason this won't work is because the number of armorstands can change, and I need to run the same command for each armour stand; I can't just have each armour stand create a different player scoreboard objective , and then update that scoreboard objective within a tellraw clickEvent, and then I can't check all of those variable number of different scoreboard objectives using another line of command blocks. It just won't work.